# Unit-testing ngResource $save

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-resource

I have a resource which wraps a RESTful API.  I use that resource from my controller to create new objects and save them, similar to this snippet from the Angular docs:

```
var newCard = new CreditCard({number:'0123'});
newCard.name = "Mike Smith";
newCard.$save();
```

When writing a unit test in Jasmine, I get the following error when the $save call is executed: "Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined".

What's the best approach to testing the method in my controller which contains the above code?

Comment: Maybe you should show the code that triggers the error. My guess is that you are spying on a resource method that is supposed to be setting a $promise property ... When you use spyOn() the original function is replaced with one that does the spying... the original function is not executed, so no promise is ever returned/set. But you can do `spyOn(resource, "$save").and.callThrough()` to get the spy functionality and the original function to be executed.

Comment: You're right Sunil.  The spyOn was spyOn(_cardService, 'save');  When I add the callThrough, it executes the test without the promise error.  If you move your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was resolved, posted that as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Jasmine's `spyOn()` function to verify that a `$resource` method is called, it overwrites the original `$resource` method with one that implements the "spying" functionality.

If the code in your application relies on the `$resource` setting the $promise property, or it relies on the returned object/array from the `$resource`, the Jasmine's spy function won't return anything or set a value on the $promise property. As a result, perfectly fine code in your application will fail when being tested. A similar thing happens when you use `$http` with the `then()`, `success()`, or `error()` functions.

To work around that you can make Jasmine spy on the function as well as call the original function by doing something like this:

```
// Newer Jasmine 2.0 syntax:
spyOn(resource, "$save").and.callThrough();
// Older syntax:
spyOn(resource, "$save").andCallThrough();
```