# Test state redirection in Angular using ui.router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I've a profileController Controller which has an activate method which redirects the user to the home page if it is not authenticated.
I'd like to test such functionality.

The Controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('nocc.profile.controllers', [])
    .controller('ProfileController', ProfileController);

ProfileController.$inject = ['request', '$state', 'profileService'];

/**
 * @namespace ProfileController
 * @description Controller of the profile view
 */
function ProfileController(request, $state, profileService) {
    var vm = this;

    activate();

    /**
     * @summary Activates the controller
     * @description Actions to be performed when this controller is instantiated
     * @memberOf nocc.profile.controllers.ProfileController
     */
    function activate() {
        // If the user is not authenticated, he should not be here.
        if (!request || !request.user) {
            $state.go('home', {}, {reload: true});
        }
    }



 }
 })();
```

So I have a link in my topbar which calls `state.go('profile')`. The routing is defined this way:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('nocc.profile.routes', ['ui.router'])
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

/**
 * @summary config
 * @description Defines profile routes
 */
function config( $stateProvider ) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        parent: 'loggedIn',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'ProfileController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: 'profile/templates/profile.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ page_title: 'Profile' }
    });
}
})();
```

All works as expected. I'd like to write a test for the redirection, I ended with this:

```
describe( 'profile', function() {

var authenticationService, rootScope, scope1, state, controller;

beforeEach( module( 'nocc' ) );
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $state) {
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    scope1 = $rootScope.$new();
    state = $state;
    controller = $controller;
    spyOn($state, 'go');

}));

/**
 * Profile page should redirect to home page if user's not authenticated
 */
it( 'checking profile when non authenticated', function() {
    state.go('profile');
    rootScope.$digest();
    expect(state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('profile');
    state.go.reset();
    controller('ProfileController', {
        request: {},
        $scope: scope1,
        $state: state
    });
    expect(state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home', {}, {reload: true});
});

});
```

The test is ok, it is successfull. But I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing here. In particular I thought that I don't need to instantiate the controller inside the test, because I thought that it was instantiated as a consequence of calling `state.go('profile')`. But if I remove the Controller instantiation, it turns out that `state.go` is called only once with the param 'profile', so the redirectin doesn't occurr. Clearly this is not the case in the running application, since the controller is instantiated when changing state and the activate function gets executed and redirects to the home page.

So is this the behavior of tests? Why a `state.go` call doesn't instantiate the state controller and I've to instantiate it manually? Is the test I wrote the right one to test such redirection?

Comment: This might be a duplicate... Here is [an answer I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27064945/398606) that explains at what is happening when you `spyOn()` a function. You need to change your spy syntax accordingly in the `beforeEach()`. The syntax varies based on which version of Jasmine you're using.

Comment: @SunilD. thanks, but the same happens without using `spyOn`. If I only check `state.current.name` after `state.go('profile')` I see that current state is profile, so the redirection doesn't occurr

Comment: @abidibo did you find any solution to check if the transition occurs? Because, your case is exactly what I want to test. Currently, I'm in a 'search' state, but after doing $state.go('home'), I check $state.current.name, but it's still 'search' when I am expecting to be 'home'.